Solving a quadriatic (covariance) constraint with a quadratic optimizer that only takes linear constraints
I am currently working with Python and am for various reasons limited to (quadratic) optimizers like cvxopt that only take linear constraints.
I unfortunately now have to solve an optimization problem that has a quadratic constraint, more specifically a constraint that limits the covariance below a threshold.
Specifically I have the following constraint:
x SIGMA x' <= Threshold , where x is an investment vector (that is to be optimized) and Sigma the covariance matrix.
Is there any way to either linearize this or rewrite the problem into one that can be solved with cvxopt or other quadratic optimizers?
The full problem with objective function currently looks like this
minimize (x - constant vector)^2
s.t. x SIGMA x' <= Threshold
